# I can't run react-native project on android simulator

Tags: react-native

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the advise the error message?  Do you have an Android emulator or device up and running? Can you connect to it with adb?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Android SDK Manager (on Mac start a new shell and run
   android); in the window that appears make sure you check:

   - Android SDK Build-tools version 23.0.1
   - Android 6.0 (API 23)
   - Local Maven repository for Support Libraries (this is called Android Support Repository in older versions)
2. Click "Install Packages"
   [image]